# crossbar in r with computed confidence interval and computed mean

Tags: r, ggplot2

my table looks like this:

```
    name                 mean        confi_low      confi_high
    factor 1            0.107929704  -0.005593772   0.221453181
    factor 2            0.166226365   0.069457719   0.262995011
    factor 3            -0.080056702 -0.200222151   0.040108748
    factor 4            0.158344295   0.025713561   0.290975028
    factor 5            0.188088223  0.097130584    0.279045862
    factor 6            0.097839971 -0.008014220    0.203694161
```

I would like to create a crossbar graph that has confi_low as lower border, confi_high as upper border and mean marked. Can anyone help me?
I am very thankful for every hint

Comment: Why would you want to draw a boxplot using means and confidence intervals? Wouldn't that be quite misleading? Perhaps you want `geom_crossbar`?

Comment: Oh, you are totally right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also wouldn't use Boxplots for that. You could make a barplot with errorbars:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = name, y = mean)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = confi_low, ymax = confi_high)) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = c("mean and 95% CI"))
```

[image]

Or with `geom_point`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = name, y = mean)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = confi_low, ymax = confi_high), width = 0.3) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = c("mean and 95% CI"))
```

[image]

---

*Edit*
Plot means in ascending order:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = fct_reorder(name, mean), y = mean)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = confi_low, ymax = confi_high), width = 0.3) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = c("mean and 95% CI"))
```

Comment: Oh this is perfect! Thank you a lot. I dont know if this is too much to ask for but Is there any possibility to plot the means in ascending order?

Comment: You're welcome! We can do that with `x = fct_reorder(name, mean)` (see updated answer)

Comment: Hey, sorry for bothering you again. I have another question: I have another quite similar table and I would like to plot them separately from each other in one graph. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: You could use the `cowplot` package