# How to plot a grouped Crossbar graph with error plots with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

my table looks like this:

```
                   name              mean           median   confi_low       confi high
1               factor1        865.04343        132.1322    1.2720944         18.163728      1
2               factor2        21.643254        98.07801    3.5228677         987.27607      1
3               factor3        5.14328320      -98.56740    2.8130112         95.79901      1
4              factor 4        112.744184       9.2642842   2.4775374         953.5526      2
5              factor 5        -6.493834        5.01283721  3.3698789         10.10956      2
```

I would like to create a crossbar graph with error plots that has confi_low as lower border, confi_high as upper border and mean marked. Further, I want to group the plots based on its age and to separate both groups from each other, however all plots should be in one graph. Further, the plots should be ordered in ascending order within each group. This was my approach:

```
ggplot(graphdata, aes(x = fct_reorder(name, mean), y = mean, group = factor)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, color = "black") +
  geom_col(width = 0.5, color = "grey", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_point(size=2.5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = confid_low, ymax = confi_high), width = 0.2) +
  theme_classic()
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is this related to a previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62523234/crossbar-in-r-with-computed-confidence-interval-and-computed-mean. Please include your data in a reproducible format i.e. use `dput(graphdata)`, Check out [mre] to make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: My data frame is too big to post it here. I just stated the first 5 rows of my data frame to keep it simple. And yes, it is related to my last question. I though that I should open a new once because I already marked it as solved.

Comment: Ok thanks for this: Then include `dput(head(graphdata, 10))` as a sample of your data.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my table.

Comment: @Momentum4Ever Please include `age` and `mean` in your sample data. It is not reproducible.

Comment: Oh sorry, I also changed the names in the code. It should be reproducible now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this. I have created `factor2` to show how multiple plots are created:

```
graphdata %>% mutate(factor2=rep(c(1,2),5)) -> graphdata

ggplot(graphdata, aes(x = reorder(name,serialcorrelation), y = serialcorrelation, group = factor)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, color = "black") +
  geom_col(width = 0.5, color = "grey", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_point(size=2.5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = confidenceint_low, ymax = confidenceint_high), width = 0.2) +facet_wrap(~factor2)+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

[image]